# Problem with MEF

Tags: asp.net, mef

I have the folllowing:

```
private void ConfigureMEFContainer()
    {
        _catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(_pluginsPath);
        _container = new CompositionContainer(_catalog);
    }

       private readonly string _pluginsPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Plugins");
    private DirectoryCatalog _catalog;
    private CompositionContainer _container;
```

Container is passed to another class:

```
        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        batch.AddPart(this);

        container.Compose(batch);

        [ImportMany(typeof(IOnAnnotationCreatedPlugin))]
    public Lazy<IOnAnnotationCreatedPlugin, IAnnotationPluginMetadata>[] OnCreatedPlugins { get; set; }

    [ImportMany(typeof(IOnAnnotationCreatingPlugin))]
    public Lazy<IOnAnnotationCreatingPlugin, IAnnotationPluginMetadata>[] OnCreatingPlugins { get; set; }

    [ImportMany(typeof(IOnAnnotationUpdatedPlugin))]
    public Lazy<IOnAnnotationUpdatedPlugin, IAnnotationPluginMetadata>[] OnUpdatedPlugins { get; set; }

    [ImportMany(typeof(IOnAnnotationUpdatingPlugin))]
    public Lazy<IOnAnnotationUpdatingPlugin, IAnnotationPluginMetadata>[] OnUpdatingPlugins { get; set; }
```

All the collections above are empty!

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. I changed the code to the following and now it works fine. I believe, I had a problem with the custom Export Attribute and the Metadata interface. Here is the complete code in case someone else had the same problem:

```
public interface IAnnotationServicePluginMetadata
{
    string Name { get; }

    [DefaultValue(0)]
    int Priority { get; }
}

[MetadataAttribute]  
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=false)]  
public class AnnotationServicePluginMetadataAttribute : ExportAttribute  
{
   public AnnotationServicePluginMetadataAttribute()
       : base(typeof(IAnnotationServicePluginMetadata))
   {
   }  

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

Using the above:

```
[Export(typeof(IOnAnnotationUpdatedPlugin))]
[AnnotationServicePluginMetadata(Name = "OnUpdatedPlugin", Priority = 1)]
public class OnUpdatedPlugin : IOnAnnotationUpdatedPlugin
{ }
```

Properties as follows:

```
    [ImportMany(typeof(IOnAnnotationUpdatedPlugin))]
    public IEnumerable<Lazy<IOnAnnotationUpdatedPlugin, IAnnotationServicePluginMetadata>> OnUpdatedPlugins { get; set; }
```

Hope that helps.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm can't see what's wrong, but here's a blog post on how to debug this type of thing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2010/07/13/how-to-debug-and-diagnose-mef-failures.aspx

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. I debugged the Catalog and I was able to see the only Assembly found in the "Plugins" folder. Seems the problem is in composing itself as Exports/Imports are not being matched. Any ideas?

Comment: @bhaidar There are a lot of reasons the exports might not match the imports.  They are listed in the blog post I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the alternative:

```
container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Also, have you ensured that you've specified the type on export, e.g.

```
[Export(typeof(IOnAnnotationCreatedPlugin))]
```

Instead of simply:

```
[Export]
```

The latter will export the concrete type with a contract for the concrete type, not the interface.

Comment: Can you post your definition of `IAnnotationPluginMetadata` also.